# xml schema attributes required or not?

Tags: xsd

I have one XML schema. i am new to it. My question is: are these attributes required to validate the XML? In other words, should i include these attributes in my XML file?

```
<s:complexType name="OTA_TravelItineraryRQ">
 <s:sequence>
   <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="POS" type="tns:POS"/>
 </s:sequence>
 <s:attribute name="EchoToken" type="s:string"/>
 <s:attribute name="TimeStamp" type="s:dateTime"/>
</s:complexType>
```

Because this is small part of the the xml schema, i can not test it partly. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attributes **EchoToken** and **TimeStamp** are optional by default. This menas that even if you  will not use them the validation will be successful. To specify that the attributes are required, use the use="required" attribute i.e:

```
<s:attribute name="EchoToken" type="s:string" use="required"/>
<s:attribute name="TimeStamp" type="s:dateTime" use="required"/>
```

Cheers,

J.